# Redirection inside Controller.OnAuthorization in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is my issue.
I have 2 roles one for "Administrator" and the last for "Client". In my HomeController I have the action "Index" which I wish to be accessed only by "Administrator" role. So when I have x user authenticated that has not "Administrator" role, I want him not to be redirected to the login page (set in my web config file) but to an particular action. Here is my code

```
[Authorize(Roles="Administrator")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<object> users = new List<object>();
        foreach (MembershipUser u in Membership.GetAllUsers())
        {
            users.Add(u);
        }            
        return View(users);
    }        
    protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && !User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
        {
            if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl == "/")
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(Url.Action("Denied"));
            }
            //filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/Denied");
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }                    
    }
    //this action is for any authenticated user
    [Authorize]       
    public ActionResult Denied()
    {
        return View(User.Identity.Name);
    }
```

This issue throws System.invalidoperationexception and ~/Views/Home/xyz.cshtml does not exist. Of course the views url should be ~/Views/Home/denied.cshtml
For information "xyz" is the UserName authenticated. How can I do redirection?
Thanks

Comment: `return View(User.Identity.Name);` is throwing the error you're seeing

Comment: if you're trying to return the name of the User you need to specify that `User.Identity.Name` is the Model by using `return View(model: User.Identity.Name);`

Comment: You're right, first string parameter within View constructor match with a view name. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast your model to object.

```
[Authorize]       
public ActionResult Denied()
{
    return View((object)User.Identity.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your if statement might be off a little.  try this

```
if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || !User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
```